# Necessary to apply Magento PHP 7.2 patch before installing SUPEE-10888?

Tags: magento-1, patches, supee-10888

I'm running **Magento 1.9.2.1** and patched up to **SUPEE-10752**.

I'm wanting to apply the **SUPEE-10888** patch, but it's not clear to me from the documentation whether or not the **PHP 7.2 patch**, which was released between **SUPEE-10752** and **SUPEE-10888** is a requirement for **SUPEE-10888** or not.

Do **SUPEE-10888** (and therefore other future patches) base themselves off of changes made in the PHP 7.2 patches?